# How do I restrict keyboard focus to controls within a Node?

Tags: javafx-2

I'm trying to implement a reusable method for displaying a node as a lightweight dialog. The node is added to the top of a StackPane while the background is then blurred. There are 2 problems:

1) Controls in the background node of the stackpane are still able to receive focus.

2) How do I give focus to the top-level node. I know there is a requestFocus method on Node, but I need to give it to a control nested within the node. Since this is intended to be a reusable method, I can't reference the controls directly.

(if I can sidestep the whole problem by finding an existing implementation, that would be best, but I haven't found a 3rd party solution yet)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For:
1) 3 alternative suggestions,
**a-** Add a key event handler to the dialogbox pane to catch the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key pressings

```
dialogbox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            System.out.println("TAB pressed");
            event.consume(); // do nothing
        }
    }
});
```

**b-** Temporarily disable all children of the main `StackPane` except the lastly added dialogbox child.

```
// Assuming dialogbox is at last in the children list
for(int i=0; i<mainPane.getChildren().size()-1; i++){
     // Disabling will propagate to sub children recursively
    mainPane.getChildren().get(i).setDisable(true);
}
```

**c-** Same as **b** but manually disable focusing to controls by `node.setFocusTraversable(false)` (spot kick). Surely this will not be your choice..

2) Tell the dialogbox which node should take the focus after the dialog is shown (through constructor or setter method).

```
// init dialogbox and show it then
dialogbox.setFocusTo(node_in_dialogbox);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. For my case, **b** seems to work the best. For (2), I guess I could use a builder pattern to do what you're suggesting. Ideally though I was hoping for something like Swing's KeyboardFocusManager, but I'll mark your answer as "correct" since this seems to be the only way to achieve what I need for now. Thanks!