# javafx - make ListView not selectable via mouse

Tags: listview, javafx, selection

Is there an option in JavaFX to deactivate the possibility to select the items in a `ListView` via mouse?

I'd like to just display a `ListView` without any user interaction possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could also try:

```
listview.setMouseTransparent( true );
listView.setFocusTraversable( false );
```

Comment: But can you still scroll in the listview when using these settings?

Comment: No, you can't scroll a list with these settings.

Answer (score 23):

Setting the list to mouse transparent will also prevent cells with interactable custom list cells from accepting focus.

The ideal solution is to use a special selection model:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel;

public class NoSelectionModel<T> extends MultipleSelectionModel<T> {

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<T> getSelectedItems() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectIndices(int index, int... indices) {
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAll() {
    }

    @Override
    public void selectFirst() {
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLast() {
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int index) {
    }

    @Override
    public void select(int index) {
    }

    @Override
    public void select(T obj) {
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int index) {
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int index) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void selectPrevious() {
    }

    @Override
    public void selectNext() {
    }
}
```

Then set the model in the list view:

```
listView.setSelectionModel(new NoSelectionModel<MyType>());
```

Comment: Good solution for custom list cells, like you said.

Comment: This is a perfect solution for use cases with custom list cells - however if you want to avoid the focus-outline of caspian/modena.css you'll have to additionally add `listView.setFocusTraversable(false)`, which is probably what you want anyway, given that your cells shouldn't be selectable.

Comment: An alternative to setting the `focusTraversable` property to false, as shown by @Folling, is to do the same thing as in the answer except with the `FocusModel` (see [`ListView#focusModel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#focusModelProperty())). That will allow the `ListView` to remain focusable but will prevent the outline on focused cells (at least, it did for me).

Comment: Just to add another alternative, depending on what you actually need an "always empty" selection/focus model for you may be able to simply style the cells differently using CSS so they don't _look_ selected/focused even when they are.

Answer (score 8):

You may block your list view mouse click buy using event handler

```
listview.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println(">> Mouse Clicked");
                event.consume();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Mordechai's approach works really great.
I tried to comment with another addition for JFoenix JFXListView but the code formatting wasn't good so I created this answer:

If you are using JFoenix and  the JFXListView you have also the behaviour that you can still see the JFXRippler on cell selection.
 To prevent this or change the rippler override the cell factory:

```java
//Replace T with your specific type.
listView.setCellFactory(param -> new JFXListCell<T>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        cellRippler = new JFXRippler(); //create empty rippler
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Pointe you to the right direction?
restrict focus[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197048/how-do-i-restrict-keyboard-focus-to-controls-within-a-node)

If not maybe setting a custom FocusModel could help?

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Override
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    updateSelected(false);
}
```

Every time you click on a cell, the cell's updateItem will call, so you can deselect it at here. If you check the base class Cell.java. It use this method to prevent empty cell being selected.

```java
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    setItem(item);
    setEmpty(empty);
    if (empty && isSelected()) {
        updateSelected(false);
    }
}
```