# JavaFX - Change ListView's FocusModel

Tags: java, eclipse, listview, javafx

I have a ListView and am currently overriding the SelectionModel to prevent selection of the items, but when you attempt to select an item, it is still showing the outline.

Reading over the API, I found that I can do the same thing but this time by overriding the FocusModel using

```
    listView.setFocusModel(new SettingsFocusModel<VBox>());
```

And here is my SettingsFocusModel

```
public class SettingsFocusModel<T> extends FocusModel<T> {
    @Override
    protected int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected T getModelItem(int index) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is not working as intended, though. I can still see the outline as if I did not override the FocusModel. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your application use case with a ListView without selected item(s)?

Comment: @CemIkta I am using a ListView to display items in Settings page in their own sections (VBox). I want the items themselves to be usable (of course) but I do not want the user to be able to select the individual VBox sections.

Comment: It may be a better approach to simply change the style of selected/focused cells in your settings dialog.

Comment: @Slaw You are correct, thank you. I was initially on this route because I had seen one of your previous comments about the ListView.focusModel where you did this same thing.

Comment: @piggy I remember making such an answer or comment somewhere. I don't remember having the problem you're having in this question, however. In any case, I believe changing the style is the easier and more appropriate solution.

Comment: @piggy Can you link me to where I made the comments? I want to at least mention CSS there if neither I nor anyone else already has.

Comment: Absolutely, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186195/7987450. I also posted another answer on this question which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my specific case, I ended up doing the following:

```
listView.setSelectionModel(new SettingsSelectionModel<VBox>());
listView.getStyleClass().add("settings-view");
```

SettingsSelectionModel follows the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186195/7987450

My css file includes:

```
    .list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color: null;
}

.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: null;
}

.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: null;
}
```

I chose to set the background color to null each time because this works in both Dark and Light modes.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your ListView CSS to prevent this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getStyleClass().add("list-view-unselect");
        listView.getItems().add("Item 1");
        listView.getItems().add("Item 2");
        listView.getItems().add("Item 3");

        VBox vbox = new VBox(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 640, 480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX App");
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

And style.css:

```
.list-view-unselect .list-cell:filled:selected:focused,
.list-view-unselect .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.list-view-unselect .list-cell:even {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
.list-view-unselect .list-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. For my specific case, I ended up having to do something a little different, I posted my answer aswell.